# Get hours, minutes and seconds, ... from Unix epoch at UTC

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I've been chasing my tail with JavaScript Date and thought I ask here to see if anyone could help.

From a Unix epoch value (millisonds), I'd like to extract the date components (day, month, ..., hours, min) to display them in JavaScript.

For instance this Epoch time `1674434520` (23 January 2023 00:42:00) should give

```
day=23
month=1 (or 0, when 0-based, I don't mind)
year=2023
hour=0
minute=42
```

The problem is that in order to convert all the datetime components, I need to convert the Unix epoch number into a JavaScript date (`new Date(epoch)`) at which time, it'll assume my browser's local time zone settings (which is not GMT) [1].

I'd like to be able to extract the datetime components regardless of the local browser settings.

Any idea how this can be achieved without external libraries? If possible, I would like to avoid unnecessary parsing/formatting ( `Intl.DateTimeFormat` approach) or shifting of the date (to avoid potential leap year/daylight saving issues).

---

[1] when displaying the dates using devtools or accessing getHours(), etc (clarified what I meant by "assume" based on @Bergi's comment).

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl

Comment: I did have a look at the `Intl.DateTimeFormat`, but from what I can tell, it serves the purpose of formatting dates. I could apply a formatter for each datetime component and parse it back to an integer value, but I was hoping there's a more direct way of achieving this.

Comment: "*at which time, it'll assume my browser's local time zone settings*" - no. That is only happening when you display the date object anywhere (including devtools), using `.toString()`. Just use the `getUTC…()` methods instead.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston Not necessary.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for @Bergi. I was using `getHours`, etc, not knowing that there are special `getUTC...` functions. Thanks so much!